# Ajax dojo in function ignore before the call lines

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I'm trying to execute one function that have the following structure:

```
query(myDivBlock).style('display','block');
query(myModal).style('display','block');

dojo.xhrGet(callajax);

query(myDivBlock).style('display','none');
query(myModal).style('display','none');
```

My problem is that in Firefox the code executes fine, but in IE9, IE10 and Chrome it does not. They ignore the lines before and after the Ajax call. I have already configured it as Ajax sync and did not work.

Anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: How did you configure it in sync mode? Maybe post more code

Comment: There is a property sync that set with true did the call ajax sync. I am using the following link as an example: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/xhrGet.html

Comment: Where before the call ajax define one booleab variable whith true and during the call this value of the variable can change, in the end of the execution return the variable value. But during the executin I need block the user screen

Answer (score 0):

dojo.xhrGet blocks browser execution but not browser rendering.
This will work cross browser:

```
query(myDivBlock)[0].style('display','block');
query(myModal)[0].style('display','block');

dojo.xhrGet({url: "url",
             sync: true,
             load: function(data){
                    query(myDivBlock)[0].style('display','none');
                    query(myModal)[0].style('display','none');
             }
);
```

Comment: Ferry, I already tried this way, but in the IE and Chrome not execute the query line block and hidden

Comment: I've edited my answer. 'query' returns an array of elements, that is the reason why it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, but I believe that this is not the problem. Because the object query works even without the index, it applies the style to all elements.